# Dapper can't map bit columns to boolean fields

Tags: dapper

I have a bit column in the SQL Server 2008 database and I am trying to use Dapper to map it to my object that has boolean fields that match the bit columns. I get invalid cast exceptions as Dapper is trying to say the columns are ints. How do I get it to map a bit to a bool? Also, will there ever be decent documentation for this ORM?

Comment: it should work out of the box, could you please post the code ?

Comment: I found the problem. The stored procedure was using coalesce on the column which was casting it as an int. I would delete this question but I don't know how.

Comment: I don't think is a good idea to delete the question since it is useful as a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. The stored procedure was using coalesce on the column which was casting it as an int.

Answer (score 2):

Is the column nullable ? If this is the case try to structure the dto with a property of type `bool?` instead of just `bool`, to handle the DbNull value correctly. The better documentation is the code itself [and the project home](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Comment: `Dapper` version `1.50.2.0` seems to map `NULLABLE BITs` in sql to a `c# bool`, at least a `1` BIT to a `true`.